# SDF (Chemical Table File) parser in any language

Tags: csv, parser

I'm looking to parse a large .sdf file and put it into a CSV.

The only software I could find that parses .sdf files is OpenBabel's Pybel, but it won't properly install for my El Capitan, for either python2.7 or 3.+ (it's an open issue, and might hopefully be fixed with the next release).

Are there any other languages/OSS that can easily parse this file? As well, if there aren't, is there a recommended operating system I could spin up with VirtualBox that will easily run OpenBabel/Pybel?

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenEyes library](https://docs.eyesopen.com/toolkits/python/quickstart-python/index.html) supports reading from MOD SD Files and writing to .csv files as you can see [here](https://docs.eyesopen.com/toolkits/python/oechemtk/molreadwrite.html) along with a large number of others of course.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from openeye.oechem import *

ifs = oemolistream()
ofs = oemolostream()

ifs.SetFormat(OEFormat_SDF)
ofs.SetFormat(OEFormat_CSV)

for mol in ifs.GetOEGraphMols():
    OEWriteMolecule(ofs, mol)
```

It may be a good idea to follow the [advice](https://docs.eyesopen.com/toolkits/python/quickstart-python/linuxosx.html) on setting up a virtual-env.